# determining a convolution of an arithmetic function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-convolution

Let be 
$ \lambda: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
be an arithmetic function 
$$ \lambda (n) := (-1)^{e_1+\dots+e_r} $$
where $p_1^{e_1}...p_r^{e_r} $ is the prime factorization of $n$
and it is $ \lambda (1)=1$.

My question is how can I determine the convolution $ \lambda \ast \lambda$ ?

The convolution of two  arithmetic fuctions is given by

$$( \phi \ast \lambda)(n) := \sum_{d | n} \phi(d) \lambda (n | d) $$

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: It is multiplicative, thus so is $f=\lambda \ast \lambda$, thus it suffices to find $f(p^k)$

Comment: okay, i have found out that this is the multiplicative moebius function..hmm, can you please explain how to find $f(p^k) $?

Comment: $\lambda$ is the completely multiplicative version of $\mu$. Well $f(p^k) = \sum_{m=0}^k \lambda(p^m)\lambda(p^{k-m})=...$ thus $\lambda(n) f(n)=...$

Comment: @helloworld1235 Note that the person who asked can vote answers and mark one of them as "accepted". See https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The    *[Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function)*  $\lambda$ is *[completely  multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function)*, i.e.
\begin{align*}
&\lambda(1)=1\\
&\lambda(m\cdot n)=\lambda(m)\lambda(n)\qquad m,n\in\mathbb{N}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain for $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\lambda\ast\lambda\right)(n)}&=\sum_{d\mid n}\lambda(d)\lambda\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{d\mid n}\lambda(n)\tag{2}\\
> &=\lambda(n)\sum_{d\mid n}1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\lambda(n)\tau(n)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the complete multiplicative property of $\lambda$.
- In (3) we use the divisor function $\tau$, the number of positive divisors of $n$.