# Dirichlet Convolution of λ*u(n)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, dirichlet-convolution

For two multiplicative arithmetic functions , the Dirichlet convolution is defined by $(∗)()=∑_{·=n}=()(). $

Let u(n) be the function that is 1 for all n and define λ(n) = $(-1)^{e_1 + e_2 +...+e_n }$ where n has prime factorization $n = {p_1}^{e_1}·...·{p_n}^{e_n} $

Find a closed form for λ*u(n).

Notes: so in the formula for calculating the Dirichlet convolution the u(b) term will be 1 for each term so it should just be the sum of λ(d) over all d which divide n. My thoughts are that the closed form depends on n's prime factorization and the sum of the coefficients on all the primes, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Same answer as in your classmate question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463014/determining-a-convolution-of-an-arithmetic-function?noredirect=1#comment7119654_3463014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n= p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(g*f)(n) &=& \sum_{d \mid n} \lambda(d) =\sum_{i_{1}=0}^{e_1} \sum_{i_{2}=0}^{e_2} \cdots \sum_{i_{k}=0}^{e_k} (-1)^{i_1+i_2 +\cdots+i_k} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=& \sum_{i_1=0}^{e_1} (-1)^{i_1} \sum_{i_2=0}^{e_2} (-1)^{i_2} \cdots \sum_{i_k=0}^{e_k} (-1)^{i_k}  \\
\end{eqnarray*} 
Now note that $\sum_{i_j=0}^{e_j} (-1)^{i_j}$ is zero if  $e_j$ is odd and $1$ if it is even, so we require all the exponenets to be even, in other words $n$ must be an exact square.

So the convolution $1$ if $n$ is a square and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't realize to use the fact that I could just see what it did to each prime and then use the fact that's it's multiplicative